# Creating class labels for custom DataSets efficiently (HuggingFace)

Tags: nlp, transformer, huggingface

I have pandas dataframes - test & train,they both have `text` and `label` as columns as shown below -

```
 label       text
 fear        ignition problems will appear 
 joy         enjoying the ride
```

As usual, to run any Transformers model from the HuggingFace, I am converting these dataframes into `Dataset` class, and creating the classLabels (fear=0, joy=1) like this -

```
from datasets import DatasetDict 

traindts = Dataset.from_pandas(traindf)
traindts = traindts.class_encode_column("label")

testdts = Dataset.from_pandas(testdf)
testdts = testdts.class_encode_column("label")
```

Finally these `Datasets` are put into `DatasetDict`like this-

```
emotions = DatasetDict({
    "train" : traindts , 
    "test" : testdts 
})
```

Everything works well but as you see that the way I am doing it can be definitely improved. How can it be done more efficiently in less number of lines ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a coding style issue, so people may well have different opinions! But I don't see any problem with the way you've coded it.

If you really want to reduce the number of lines of code you could combine the two assignments to traindts into one statement, and the same with testdts:

```
traindts = Dataset.from_pandas(traindf).class_encode_column("label")
testdts = Dataset.from_pandas(testdf).class_encode_column("label")
```

If you don't use traindts and testdts anywhere else, you could then even remove the assignment statements altogether and move all the code into the call to DatasetDict:

```
emotions = DatasetDict({
    "train" : Dataset.from_pandas(traindf).class_encode_column("label"), 
    "test" : Dataset.from_pandas(traindf).class_encode_column("label") 
})
```

But then you are sacrificing readability for fewer lines of code. So if it were me, I *probably* would make the first change, but wouldn't bother with the second one.

Answer (score 0):

1. you  can combine data of test and train in a single data frame.
2. Then you should split data frame using scalar test train split